# How can I concatenate first and last name in powershell

Tags: powershell

```
FirstName,LastName,passcode,Title,Manager_Email
zack,Ased,breast<achievement?&childhood059,manager,zasdasdh@gmail.com
```

How can I make the Name zack Ased and the username zack.Ased , here is the code I tried

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ADUsers = Import-Csv C:\users.csv
foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
    $FirstName = $User.FirstName
    $LastName = $User.LastName
    $Name = $FirstName + " " + $LastName
    $username =  $FirstName.$LastName
    $password = $User.passcode
    $Title = $User.Title
    $Manager_Email = $User.Manager_Email
    New-ADUser -Name $Name -SamAccountName $username -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-secureString $password -AsPlainText -Force) -Title $Title -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
    Enable-AdAccount -Identity $username
    }
```

Comment: `$Name = $FirstName + " " + $LastName` looks correct to form the name,  `$username = $FirstName.$LastName` is missing double-quotes: `"$FirstName.$LastName"`

Answer (score 1):

using -join:

```
$FirstName = 'John'
$LastName = 'Smith'

$Name = $FirstName, $LastName -join " " 
#the " " is the delimiter, you can input whatever you like, for example a dot:
$Name = $FirstName, $LastName -join "."
```

see more examples on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join

Another method is by putting it in a new string:

```
$Name = "$($FirstName).$($LastName)"
```

There are several other possible methods of doing this.